# Swashbuckle (non-Core) configuration modification at runtime

Tags: swashbuckle

Using the non-Core version of Swashbuckle (https://github.com/domaindrivendev/Swashbuckle), is there a way to modify the configuration after the application has launched?  I cannot find a way to do this out of the box.

As an example, let's say I want to modify this at some point while the application is running:

```
.EnableSwaggerUi(c =>
    {
        c.SupportedSubmitMethods("GET");
    });
```

Is this possible without modifying Swashbuckle itself?

Answer (score 0):

Look into **IDocumentFilters** they get executed at runtime. 
I have a few examples here:
[SwashbuckleTest/blob/master/Swagger_Test/App_Start/SwaggerConfig.cs](https://github.com/heldersepu/SwashbuckleTest/blob/master/Swagger_Test/App_Start/SwaggerConfig.cs#L347)

And that `EnableSwaggerUi( c => SupportedSubmitMethods )` is something that happens on the browser client side, you can change that behavior with a custom JS file, look in the config for **InjectJavaScript**.

You can also overwrite the default assets used in the swagger-ui (such as the [index.html](https://github.com/domaindrivendev/Swashbuckle/blob/master/Swashbuckle.Core/SwaggerUi/CustomAssets/index.html)) with your own version, look in the config for **CustomAsset**

Comment: Thank you for the examples, however I don't need to make any changes to the swagger document itself, but rather the behavioral code of the UI.   Unfortunately, InjectJavaScript code is fired during the onComplete event of the swagger UI process - my example of SupportedSubmitMethods has already been processed by the time any custom code would fire.  I would need to modify the value beforehand, and no such event hooks exist that I can find for onStart, onPreRender, or anything similar.  I'd have to hack the DOM, which might be what is necessary in this case.

Comment: I don't see it as a hack, you don't have to reverse engineer code or anything like that, swashbuckle & swagger-ui are OpenSource projects